# visual studio 2010 breakpint does not stop

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, c#-4.0

I have a solution with two projects. One is a dll project and the other a wpf application to test this library. This wpf projetc I have a reference to the library proejct.

When I set a breakpoint in the code of the library, it does not stop. The breakpoint is in blank with a yellow warning triangle.

I have other solutions similar to this with many projects and I can stop the code in any breakpoint in those solutions.

Thanks.

EDIT: solution.

The solution is check that the two projects has the same platform, and remove and add again the reference to the dll project in the test project, I exit and enter again in VS2010, clean and rebuild the two projects and works.

Comment: have you tried rebuilding both projects? sometimes the source code and the dlls are different from each other, causing such problems.

Comment: Yes, I try to clean and recompile both project, one of them first and later the other. But the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because another version of your DLL is used than you expect. Please check that you indeed reference the output of the DLL project not a certain DLL. Also make sure in VS configuration manager that the correct DLL is built for the platform configuration (Debug/Release, x64/x86/AnyCPU).

You may check with Process Monitor which DLL is actually used in order to find the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

If this happens to me, I do the following steps in this order. Sometimes I do no even need to do all of them.

1. Execute a solution wide "Clean".
2. Rebuild (right-click on solution)
3. Close Visual Studio
4. Delete the "bin" and "obj" folder of all projects
5. Open Visual Studio again

Also, check if you are running in DEBUG mode. :-)

Comment: In my cases this does not solve the problem, at least in this project. Although is good to know this posible solution for other cases. Thanks.